# running curl in chroot

Tags: curl, chroot

I'm trying to build some minimal container images (based on portablectl from systemd-container, which essentially uses chroot for containerization).  I'm running into a problem with some programs not being able to make HTTPS requests.  The simplest example to demonstrate is curl, and I imagine fixing curl will fix the other apps.  The disconnect appears to be related to curl finding the root certs or CA bundle.

The following command:

```
sudo chroot /etc/portables/network /usr/bin/curl -Huser-agent:example/1.0 https://www.google.com/search?q=foo
```

...results in:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

The curl binary was "installed" to the chroot using Ubuntu's package tools, and I've copied the Ubuntu root certificates from /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt in my host environment to the chroot.

This is essentially what I run to install curl and a few other network related tools (and lib dependencies) to the chroot:

```
apt-get -y install --reinstall \
    bind9-host ca-certificates curl dnsutils \
    iputils-ping \
    libasn1-8-heimdal \
    libbind9-161 libbsd0 libc6 libcap2 libcom-err2 libdns1104 libffi6 \
    libgcc1 \
    libgcrypt20 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libgpg-error0 \
    libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal \
    libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal libheimntlm0-heimdal \
    libhogweed4 libhx509-5-heimdal \
    libicu63 libidn2-0 \
    libirs161 \
    libisc1100 libisccfg163 \
    libjson-c4 libkeyutils1 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-26-heimdal \
    libkrb5support0 \
    libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common liblwres161 liblzma5 libnettle6 \
    libnghttp2-14 libp11-kit0 \
    libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 \
    libsasl2-2 libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libssl1.1 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libtasn1-6 libunistring2 libwind0-heimdal libxml2 \
    netcat-openbsd zlib1g
echo nameserver 127.0.0.53 >> /etc/resolv.conf
echo options edns0 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

Using the curl **-k** option works as expected; it ignores the cert mis-configuration and successfully makes the HTTPS request.

In addition, if I explicitly set `--cafile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, it works fine.

But if I run `curl -v`, I see the following:

```
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4007:80c::2004:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.google.com (2607:f8b0:4007:80c::2004) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

So you can see it's got CApath /etc/ssl/certs, but an empty CAfile.

Comment: could it be that curl has execute permissions to /etc/ssl/certs but not read permissions, meaning it's able to open files in the folder, but not able to read the folder itself? what do you get if you run ```sudo chroot /etc/portables/network /usr/bin/ls /etc/ssl/certs```  ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that "if curl is built against OpenSSL, the directory must have been processed using the c_rehash utility supplied  with  OpenSSL" ([curl manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--capath))

Essentially, with this curl build, the ca-certificates.crt bundle isn't used unless it's explicitly requested with `--cafile` (or `cafile=` in .curlrc).  Instead, it's looking for a specific directory layout with hashed symlinks pointing at the target files.

So, the fix is to split up the ca-certificates.crt bundle into multiple files, then run:

```
ca_rehash /etc/ssl/certs
```